# Verify baseUrl with prepended/appended text in protractor test

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm using a baseUrl in the config file and some tests access links that have prepended/appended text to the same url that needs to be verified. How can I verify the clicked url while using the baseUrl?

Example:

```
baseurl: dev.test.com
```

Link to be verified

```
this-dev.test.com/#/1234
```

'this' will not change but the numeric values will. The environment will change in the baseUrl (dev vs staging, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the currently used `baseUrl` from the `browser.params`. Then, the only thing left is to properly match the url. For this, we can use a simple `toContain()` or a more granular `toMatch()` jasmine matchers (assuming you are using Jasmine test framework):

```
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(browser.params.baseUrl);

expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch("this-" + browser.params.baseUrl + "/#/");
```

And, I am also assuming by the "clicked URL" you meant the current url - hence, the use of [`getCurrentUrl()` method](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getCurrentUrl).

You may also need to tweak things a bit if your `baseUrl` contains the protocol part (`http://` or `https://`).